# How do I merge two objects into one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, wrapper

How can we create dynamically (procedurally.... at run-time) one new object from two old objects so that operations performed on the new object are performed on both of the two old objects?

As just one example, we might have two streams:

> 1. a string stream ... `str_strm = io.StringIO()`
> 2. a file stream ... `fl_strm = open("test_file.txt", "w")`

In the example, we might want it to be that anytime we try to write a string to the new steam, copies of that string are written to the two older streams.

```python
class MergedStream:

    def __init__(strm1, strm2):
        self._strm1 = strm1
        self._strm2 = strm2

    def write(self, msg:str):
        self._strm1.write()
        self._strm2.write()
        return None 

str_strm = io.StringIO()   
fl_strm = open("test_file.txt", "w")
ms = MergedStream(str_strm, fl_strm)
```

I can ***NOT*** guarantee that the two old objects both have a method named `write`.

Our solution should be general and dynamically generate the new merged object no matter what the two old objects are.

How might we create a new object in such a way that anytime we try to act upon the new object, we perform that same action upon the two older objects?

Something like the following is a step in the right direction, but not a complete solution:

```python
class MergedObject:

    @classmethod
    def merge(cls, left, right): 
        if left == right: 
            return left 
        else: 
            return cls(left, right) 

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            r1 = self._lefty(*args, **kwargs)  
            r2 = self._righty(*args, **kwargs) 
            return type(self).merge(r1, r2)
        except AttributeError: 
            raise AttributeError() 

    def __init__(lefty, righty):
        self._lefty  = lefty
        self._righty = righty 

        reserved = dir(self) # reserved attribute names  
        attributes = dict()
        attribute_names = set(dir(lefty), dir(righty)).difference(reserved)

        for attribute_name in attribute_names:
            latter = getattr(lefty)  # `latter` is the `left-attribute`
            ratter = getattr(righty) # `ratter` is the `right-attribute`
            setattr(attribute_name, type(self).merge(latter, ratter))
```

### SOME WRINKLES TO IRON OUT

- I need to be able to merge two objects which have no overloaded `==` operator. That is, even if there is no code inside of the class definition which says `def __eq__():`, I need to test if two things are equal. Suppose I merge two objects which both have a method named `insert()` which return `-1`. I do not want to carry around duplicate values. I do not want a merged object of two copies of the number `10`, and then `x + 5` computes `10 + 5` twice.
- There are some issues with overriding python's "*magic*" methods (dunder methods) such as `__len__` or `__mul__` If the two old objects both have a `__len__` method, the new merged object might fail to have a a method named `__len__`.

Comment: You can't guarantee anything about two arbitrary objects. Perhaps you should define a protocol so you can, in fact, guarantee something. If you don't want to do that, I'd just make a list (or other collection/iterable) of the objects and let someone else worry about what it means to "merge" them.

Comment: It's unspecific and unclear. For example, what should a method of the new object return? How should a property getter or setter work?

Comment: I fear that a **general** solution is not easily feasible. But you may find different stereotypes on how to implement the merge of two functions, which could clarify/simplify the implementation (ignoreRight, checkBothCallResultsAreEqual, MedianOfTwovalues, CombineIntoPair ...). But these need to be decided on a case-by-case basis.